# ArcGIS Pro Graph - Advanced Properties Availability

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, graph, profile

ArcMap has the graph option of Right Clicking on a profile, selecting Advanced Properties, choosing the data tab, and copying all station / elevation data.

Is this available in ArcGIS Pro?

Stack Profile returns too much data for my needs, where the profile graph can provide only the locations where I click a vertice.